# ASP in a .html file under .net 4.0

Tags: iis-7, .net-4.0, web-config

I'm updating a site from asp.net 2.0 to asp.net 4.0.
I'm running IIS 7.0.
If I create test.asp and browse to it it works.
If I rename the file test.html it will not parse the asp.

I need html to be parsed as asp because of the CMS we use.

Relevant code from test.html:

```
<%
Response.Write ("The time on the server is: " & Time())
%>
```

I think my trouble comes from the way .net 4.0 handles requests.

How do I get IIS to parse html as asp?

Comment: The asp-classic tag specifically refers to pre-.Net ASP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to associate the same DLL that currently handles your .asp pages to also handle your .html pages in IIS. see [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754147%28WS.10%29.aspx) for help with that

Comment: According to [Handler Mappings](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755036(v=ws.10).aspx), don't forget that "The necessary modules and handlers must be installed on the Web server and enabled at the level at which you perform this procedure".

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the connection between ASP and .NET here.

Are you trying to figure out why the ASP engine is not processing a file with the .HTML extension?

When you name a file with the .ASP extension, it will be processed by the ASP engine. When you name a file with some other extension, like .HTML, it will not be processed by the ASP engine so any ASP-specific markup in it will go through to the client.

Comment: He's trying to map IIS to handle .html identically to .asp.. You can map whatever extension you want, last firm I worked at, we always had .l9 interpreted and handled as ASP by IIS.